# TypeError: issubclass() arg 2 must be a class or tuple of classes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I've been using the same class for months for connecting to a SQL Server database, running queries, inserting data into staging tables, etc. Just yesterday whenever my code tries to insert into a staging table, I get the error:

> TypeError: issubclass() arg 2 must be a class or tuple of classes

Debugging I learned that this is happening in the method `_relationships_for_fks` in the automap.py module (sqlalchemy library). Specifically this block fails because `referred_cls` is None and this is not supported in the `issubclass` method.

```
if local_cls is not referred_cls and issubclass(
     local_cls, referred_cls):
```

I'm on Python 3.6 and sqlalchemy version 1.2.15 (and haven't upgraded or anything lately). I have changed no code and this error has just started. Below is the class I'm using for all SQL operations in my code. Any ideas are MUCH appreciated as I cannot figure out why I keep getting this error (oh yeah and it's not always consistent - every 3 or so times, the code runs just fine). The method that fails is `get_table_class` called from the method `save_dataframe_to_table` which is called in various other places throughout my code (whenever I have to save data to a table in SQL Server I use this). The specific line of code that errors in this class is `Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)`.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

""" Connect and interact with a SQL Server database

Contains a class used for connecting and interacting with a SQL Server database.

"""

from common.Util.Logging import Logging
from common.Util.OSHelpers import get_log_filepath

import pandas
import urllib
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.exc import IntegrityError
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = automap_base()


class SqlDatabase:
    """Connect and interact with a SQL Server database"""

    def __init__(self, server, database, driver, port, username, password, logging_obj=None):
        """ Create a common.DataAccess.SqlDatabase.SqlDatabase object

        Args:
            server: (str) name of the SQL Server
            database: (str) name of the database on the SQL Server
            driver: (str) name of the driver for use in the connection string, e.g. '{ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}'
            port: (str) SQL Server port number (typically this is 1433)
            username: (str) SQL Server username (leave blank to use Windows Authentication)
            password: (str) SQL Server password (leave blank to use Windows Authentication)
            logging_obj: (common.Util.Logging.Logging) initialized logging object

        """
        # Set class variables
        if logging_obj is None:
            log_filename = get_log_filepath('Python App')
            logging_obj = Logging(name=__name__, log_filename=log_filename, log_level_str='INFO')
        self.logging_obj = logging_obj
        self.server = server
        self.database = database
        self.driver = driver
        self.port = port
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.connection_string = 'Driver=' + self.driver \
                                 + ';SERVER=' + self.server \
                                 + ',' + self.port \
                                 + ';DATABASE=' + self.database \
                                 + ';UID=' + self.username \
                                 + ';PWD=' + self.password
        # Test connection
        self.logging_obj.log(self.logging_obj.DEBUG, "method='common.DataAccess.SqlDatabase.__init__' message='Testing connection'")
        conn = self.open_connection()
        conn.close()
        # Log initialization success
        log_msg = """
        method='common.DataAccess.SqlDatabase.__init__'
        message='Initialized a SqlDatabase object' 
        server='{server}'
        database='{database}'
        driver='{driver}'
        port='{port}'
        username='{username}'
        password='{password}'
        connection_string='{connection_string}'
        """.format(server=self.server,
                   database=self.database,
                   driver=self.driver,
                   port=self.port,
                   username=self.username,
                   password='*'*len(self.password),
                   connection_string=self.connection_string)
        self.logging_obj.log(self.logging_obj.INFO, log_msg)

    def open_connection(self):
        """ Open connection

        Opens a connection to a SQL Server database.

        Returns:
            conn: (pyodbc.Connection) connection to a SQL Server database

        """
        self.logging_obj.log(self.logging_obj.DEBUG, "method='common.DataAccess.SqlDatabase.open_connection' message='Opening SQL Server connection'")
        try:
            conn = pyodbc.connect(self.connection_string)
        except Exception as ex:
            self.logging_obj.log(self.logging_obj.ERROR,
                                 """
                                 method='common.DataAccess.SqlDatabase.open_connection'
                                 message='Error trying to open SQL Server connection'
                                 exception_message='{ex_msg}'
                                 connection_string='{cxn_str}'
                                 server='{server}'
                                 port='{port}'
                                 username='{username}'
                                 password='{password}'
                                 database='{database}'""".format(ex_msg=str(ex),
                                                                 cxn_str=self.connection_string,
                                                                 server=self.server,
                                                                 port=self.port,
                                                                 username=self.username,
                                                                 password='*'*len(self.password),
                                                                 database=self.database))
            raise ex
        else:
            self.logging_obj.log(self.logging_obj.DEBUG,
                                 """
                                 method='common.DataAccess.SqlDatabase.open_connection'
                                 message='Successfully opened SQL Server connection'
                                 connection_string='{cxn_str}'
                                 server='{server}'
                                 username='{username}'
                                 password='{password}'
                                 database='{database}'""".format(cxn_str=self.connection_string,
                                                                 server=self.server,
                                                                 username=self.username,
                                                                 password='*' * len(self.password),
                                                                 database=self.database))
        return conn

    def get_engine(self):
        """ Create a Sqlalchemy engine

        Returns:
            engine: ()

        """
        self.logging_obj.log(self.logging_obj.DEBUG, "message='Creating a sqlalchemy engine'")
        params = urllib.parse.quote_plus(self.connection_string)
        try:
            engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
        except Exception as ex:
            self.logging_obj.log(self.logging_obj.ERROR,
                                 """
                                 method='common.DataAccess.SqlDatabase.get_engine'
                                 message='Error trying to create a sqlalchemy engine'
                                 exception_message='{ex_msg}'
                                 connection_string='{conn_str}'""".format(ex_msg=str(ex),
                                                                          conn_str=self.connection_string))
            raise ex
        else:
            self.logging_obj.log(self.logging_obj.DEBUG,
                                 """
                                 method='common.DataAccess.SqlDatabase.get_engine'
                                 message='Successfully created a sqlalchemy engine'
                                 connection_string='{conn_str}'
                                 """.format(conn_str=self.connection_string))
        return engine

    def get_result_set(self, query_str):
        """ Get a result set as a Pandas dataframe

        Gets a result set using the pandas.read_sql method.

        Args:
            query_str: (str) query string

        Returns:
            df: (pandas.DataFrame) result set

        """
        log_msg = """
            method='common.DataAccess.SqlDatabase.get_result_set'
            message='Getting a result set'
            query_str='{query_str}'
            """.format(query_str=query_str)
        self.logging_obj.log(self.logging_obj.INFO, log_msg)
        conn = self.open_connection()
        df = pandas.read_sql(query_str, conn)
        conn.close()
        log_msg = """
                    method='common.DataAccess.SqlDatabase.get_result_set'
                    message='Successfully got a result set'
                    query_str='{query_str}'
                    """.format(query_str=query_str)
        self.logging_obj.log(self.logging_obj.INFO, log_msg)
        return df

    def execute_nonquery(self, query_str):
        """ Execute a non-query

        Executes a non-query such as a CREATE TABLE or UPDATE statement.

        Args:
            query_str: (str) non-query statement

        Returns:

        """
        log_msg = """
            method='common.DataAccess.SqlDatabase.execute_nonquery'
            message='Executing a non-query'
            query_str='{query_str}'
            """.format(query_str=query_str)
        self.logging_obj.log(self.logging_obj.INFO, log_msg)
        conn = self.open_connection()
        curs = conn.execute(query_str)
        curs.commit()
        curs.close()
        conn.close()
        log_msg = """
                    method='common.DataAccess.SqlDatabase.execute_nonquery'
                    message='Successfully executed a non-query'
                    query_str='{query_str}'
                    """.format(query_str=query_str)
        self.logging_obj.log(self.logging_obj.INFO, log_msg)
        return None

    def to_staging_table(self,
                         dataframe,
                         staging_table_name,
                         insert_index=True,
                         index_label=None,
                         if_table_exists='replace',
                         bulkcopy_chunksize=1000):
        """ Puts a pandas.DataFrame into a staging table

        Puts a pandas.DataFrame into a staging table.
        This uses a bulk copy method to put data from a pandas.DataFrame into a SQL staging table.

        Args:
            dataframe: (pandas.DataFrame) dataframe with data to copy into a SQL server staging table
            staging_table_name: (str) name of the staging table to copy data into
            insert_index: (logical) indicates whether or not to insert an index
            index_label: (str) indicates the column name of the index - if None, an auto-generated index will be used
            if_table_exists: (str) indicates what pandas.DataFrame.to_sql method to use if the table already exists
            bulkcopy_chunksize: (int) number of rows to bulk copy at once

        Returns:

        """
        log_msg = """
            method='common.DataAccess.SqlDatabase.to_staging_table'
            message='Copying data into a staging table'
            staging_table_name='{staging_table_name}'
            """.format(staging_table_name=staging_table_name)
        self.logging_obj.log(self.logging_obj.INFO, log_msg)
        engine = self.get_engine()
        try:
            pandas.DataFrame.to_sql(
                self=dataframe,
                name=staging_table_name,
                con=engine,
                if_exists=if_table_exists,
                index=insert_index,
                index_label=index_label,
                chunksize=bulkcopy_chunksize)
        except Exception as ex:
            self.logging_obj.log(self.logging_obj.ERROR,
                                 """
                                 method='common.DataAccess.SqlDatabase.to_staging_table'
                                 message='Error trying to copy data into a staging table'
                                 exception_message='{ex_msg}'
                                 connection_string='{staging_table_name}'""".format(ex_msg=str(ex),
                                                                                    staging_table_name=staging_table_name))
            raise ex
        else:
            self.logging_obj.log(self.logging_obj.DEBUG,
                                 """
                                 method='common.DataAccess.SqlDatabase.to_staging_table'
                                 message='Successfully Copied data into a staging table'
                                 staging_table_name='{staging_table_name}'
                                 """.format(staging_table_name=staging_table_name))
        return None

    def truncate_table(self, table_name, schema_name='dbo'):
        """ Truncate a table in the SQL database

        Usually used to truncate staging tables prior to populating them.

        Args:
            table_name: (str) name of the table to truncate
            schema_name: (str) name of the schema of the table to truncate

        Returns:

        """
        query_str = "TRUNCATE TABLE {schema_name}.{table_name}".format(schema_name=schema_name, table_name=table_name)
        self.execute_nonquery(query_str)

    def get_table_class(self, table_name, engine=None):
        """ Get a table's class
        Args:
            engine:
            table_name:

        Returns:
            table_class:
        """
        if engine is None:
            engine = self.get_engine()
        Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
        base_classes = Base.classes
        for index, value in enumerate(base_classes):
            class_name = value.__name__
            if class_name == table_name:
                class_index = index
        table_class = list(base_classes)[class_index]
        return table_class

    def save_dataframe_to_table(self,
                                dataframe,
                                table_name,
                                remove_id_column_before_insert=True):
        """ Save a pandas DataFrame to a table in SQL Server

        Args:
            dataframe: (pandas.DataFrame)
            table_name: (str)

        Returns:

        """
        engine = self.get_engine()
        Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        session = Session()
        table = self.get_table_class(table_name, engine)
        if remove_id_column_before_insert:
            delattr(table, table_name+"Id")  # Id columns should always be <table_name>Id (USANA standard)
            dataframe.columns = table.__table__.columns.keys()[1:]  # Id columns should always be the first column in table (for simplicity people!)
        else:
            dataframe.columns = table.__table__.columns.keys()
        dataframe = dataframe.where((pandas.notnull(dataframe)), None)  # replace NaN with None for the bulk insert

        try:
            session.bulk_insert_mappings(table, dataframe.to_dict(orient="records"), render_nulls=True)
        except IntegrityError as e:
            session.rollback()
            self.logging_obj.log(self.logging_obj.ERROR, """method='common.DataAccess.SqlDatabase.save_dataframe_to_table' 
                                                            exception_message='{ex}'""".format(ex=str(e)))
        finally:
            session.commit()
            session.close()
```

The only other hint/clue into this issue I'm having is that I also just start getting the following warnings (for a whole set of tables in our database). I haven't seen these warnings until yesterday.

> SAWarning: This declarative base already contains a class with the same class name and module name as sqlalchemy.ext.automap.WeeklySocialSellingProductMetricsReport, and will be replaced in the string-lookup table.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem with Oracle database and it turned out that the reason was difference in letter case of schema name. Automap converts Oracle schema names and table names to lowercase, but in the `metadata.reflect(engine, schema='MYSCHEMA')` I provided my schema name in uppercase.
As a result, some tables was discovered twice:

- as `MYSCHEMA.mytable`, probably generated by plain table discovery
- as `myschema.mytable`, probably generated by a relationship discovered from another table

and caused warnings:

```
sqlalchemy\ext\declarative\clsregistry.py:129: SAWarning: This declarative base already contains a class with the same class name and module name as sqlalchemy.ext.automap.my_table_name, and will be replaced in the string-lookup table.
```

followed by `TypeError`.

The solution was as simple as changing schema name to lowercase.

This script helped me to spot table duplicates:

```
engine = create_engine(my_connection_string)

metadata = MetaData()
metadata.reflect(engine, schema='MYSCHEMA') # I'm using WRONG letter case here.

Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)

# prepend table name with schema name
def classname_for_table(base, tablename, table):
    return str(table.fullname.replace(".","__"))
Base.prepare(classname_for_table=classname_for_table)

# and look what's going on
pprint(Base.classes.keys())
```

Comment: Great answer! I have lost 2 day because of uppercase schema name. Thank you!